# запись многомерного массива циклом в БД sql

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, почему не записывает в БД

```
include"include/db_calc.php";
$zakaz = ($_POST['zakaz']);

$string = [];
foreach ($zakaz as $prod) {
$value = [];
foreach ($prod as $item) {
$value[] = "'" . $item . "'";
}
$string[] = '('.implode(', ', $value).')';
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `product` (`number`, `name`, `foto`, `raskroi`, `system`, `bead`, `uprav`, `width`, `height`, `quantity`, `price`, `price_itog`) VALUES ('".implode(', ', $string)."')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

В $query через var_export

```
'INSERT INTO `product` (`number`, `name`, `foto`, `raskroi`, `system`, 
`bead`, `uprav`, `width`, `height`, `quantity`, `price`, `price_itog`) VALUES 
(\'(\'1\', \'Слева\', \'Горизонтальные-Стандарт\', \' 9700\', 
 \'imagesbd/gor_images/gor_001.png\', \'50\', \'130\', \'\', \'1\', \'110.00 
руб.\'), (\'2\', \'Слева\', \'\', \' 9700\', 
\'imagesbd/gor_images/gor_001.png\', \'50\', \'130\', \'\', \'1\', \'0.00 
руб.\')\')'
```

Comment: Ну как минимум нужно начать с получения статуса операции записи и/или вывода сообщения об ошибке. А ещё лучше - показать, что же получилось в переменной `$query`.

Comment: может вам внутренности в какой нить json закодировать? помимо добавления параметризованных запросов вместо этого треша

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос решен, исправил тут

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `product` (`number`, `name`, `foto`, `raskroi`, `system`, `bead`, 
`uprav`, `width`, `height`, `quantity`, `price`, `price_itog`) VALUES".implode(', ', 
$string);
```

и привел количество столбцов в БД к значением в массиве.

Comment: А что если в значении кавычка попадется ?

Comment: Данные не вносятся, это грубо говоря кнопки которые передают значения.

Comment: 90% всех взломов сайтов начинаются с того, что хакер видит строку на кнопке и меняет ее на другой текст, который например заставит систему вместо текста записать в поле пароль админа, после чего его можно будет посмотреть